# Зачем пишут #ifndef file_h в начале файла

Tags: c++, c

Для каких ситуаций может быть полезно определение именно таким образом?

```
#ifndef __IMAGE_H__
#define __IMAGE_H__

////////////////////

#endif
```

Comment: чтобы код внутри не выполнялся дважды, если файл в котором это определено подключен несколько раз например

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Эти директивы предназначены для защиты от многократного включения при наличии сложной иерархии включаемых файлов - если такой файл уже был включен где-то раньше, то и `__IMAGE_H__` будет объявлена, а значит, условный `#define` будет пропущен, вместе со всеми объявлениями до `#endif`

В некоторых компиляторах есть аналогичные по действию `#pragma`, например,

```
#pragma once
```

Но версия с условием наиболее универсальна.

Comment: Во всех популярных есть `#pragma once`, так что де факто это можно считать стандартной функциональностью

Answer (score 6):

Это же классический [include guard](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), который защищает от повторного включения заголовочных файлов, чтобы не было переопределения одних и тех же функций/классов.

Answer (score 5):

Так обычно делается в заголовочных файлах, включаемых по `include`. В случае если заголовочный файл будет включен в программу дважды, это вызовет кучу ошибок типа "повторное объявление". Чтобы этого не происходило, этим `define` объявляют флаг, что файл уже включен и следовательно, когда он будет включен повторно, `ifndef` не сработает и все содержимое файла будет проигнорировано.

Comment: Не "в программу", а в одну и ту же единицу трансляции. Заголовочные файлы *предназначены* для множественного включения *в программу* и защищаться от этого, разумеется, не нужно.